# vertical align of text in floated divs

Tags: html, css

i know this question has been asked a dozen times - but it is not working in my case. I have the following code and would like to align the text to the bottom of the div.

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AzmyE

HTML:

```
<footer class="clearfix">
  <div class="footer-logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" height="60" alt="logo"/>
  </div><!-- /footer-logo -->
  <div class="footer-name">
    <span>Name Name</span><br/>
    <span class="text-gold">Creation</span>
  </div><!-- /footer-name -->
  <div class="footer-contact">
    <strong class="text-gold">T</strong> +49 (0) 1234456678<br />
    <strong class="text-gold">E</strong> test@test.de
  </div><!-- /footer-contact -->
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    height: 70px;
}

    footer p {
        margin:0;
    }

    .footer-logo, .footer-name, .footer-contact {
        float:left;
        height:100%;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .footer-name, .footer-contact {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

I have tried this also with setting the footer-name/footer-contact classes to position: relative;, created an additional div inside and set it to position: absolute; bottom:0; but this is not working properly, because the text gets wrapped.

Has anybody the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using display:table-cell can't you just get rid of the float: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4MBdt/

Comment: yes, and change margin-left to padding-left.

Comment: You are using way to much markup. all you need is three inline-block with vertical-align:bottom